# Why Does Electric Sparks cause Light?

Tags: visible-light, electricity

This question is out of curiosity, and is not really meant to be the smartest question here. 
Basically, when an electric spark occurs, why does light occur, too? From where does it come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An electric spark in a gas (or a mixture of gases such as air) occurs when the electric field is sufficiently high to remove electrons from the molecules of the gas, creating a plasma arc. This heats the gas, which causes it to glow. The heated gas in the plasma arc also expands, which is what causes the crack associated with a small spark, or the much louder bang associated with lightning.